# Create Certificate and Pass Type ID at runtime

Tags: objective-c, ios, certificate, passbook

My Passbook-related app was recently rejected based on guideline 23.3:

> 23.3: Passes must be signed by the entity that will be distributing the pass under its own name, trademark, or brand or the app will be rejected and Passbook credentials may be revoked

I had a few questions and got on the phone with someone at Apple. They told me that to remedy my problem I could create a sign-up form in my application. This sign-up form could then be used to create a certificate and pass type ID for the user based on their credentials. However, I've been combing through the documentation and I've not found anything that allows people to create Pass Type IDs or Certificates without at paid developer membership. Is this correct, **would my users need a paid developer membership to create their own Pass Type IDs?**

If they don't, is it even possible to create a PassType ID at runtime? For example, using the information in the sign-up form I might make an API request with PassKit / some kind of Passbook server to create a Pass Type ID:

```
PassID *ID = [PassKit createIDWithName:@"USER_INFO"];
```

Is there anything like that or was the Apple technician talking about something else?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly? If your users are going to need to create their own pass type IDs, then yes, the only way they can do that is via the iOS developer program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> would my users need a paid developer membership to create their own
>   Pass Type IDs

As crazy as this sounds - yes! The only way of fully satisfying this guideline is to pay the Apple Tax and sign up as a Developer.  There are several long threads in the Apple Developer Forums talking about the reasoning and implications of this. While it is not popular, the majority of us concede there are very good reasons for this, that in the long term, will protect the integrity of the platform (as well as keep the Apple lawyers happy in the short term).

The main reasoning is because in most jurisdictions; coupons, tickets, travel documents and other typical Passbook content create a binding obligation upon the issuer.  Legally, in the event of non-fulfilment, the pass issuer is liable to the consumer.  In order to protect themselves, Apple needs to ensure that under no circumstances, could they be deemed as the issuer of any Passbook pass.

The Apple Developer programme registration validates the identity of any individual or corporation who is accepted. It also forces Developers to sign the terms of the Developer Agreement which has an entire attachment dedicated to what you can and cannot do with Passbook and with your PassID certificate.  This provides Apple with enough legal protection against any claims for unfulfilled goods or services relating to any Passbook pass.

While there has been a lot of pushback and calls for a faster, less US centric process (you would not believe how difficult it is to get a DUNS number for an small entity outside of the US), I don't expect this to change any time soon.

As for auto provisioning.  Myself and the creators of the other major Passbook platforms have been calling for this since before iOS6 was launched.  I have an open radar dated 7th August requesting a simple API to issue and revoke Pass Type ID certificates.  I'm intrigued as to what your Apple Technician was referring to since as far as I am aware, there is no such service.

```
// rant
```

What is frustrating about this is that there *are* a number of approved Apps that allow full pass customisation but issue the passes under the App developer's certificate.

Apple also seem to turning a blind eye to certain services that issue passes under their own certificate that bear the logo and trademark of major brands (and then have the audacity to call on these brands to 'claim their passes').

Even Passtools (now Urban Airship) claim to offer a 'Unique Apple Developer Certificate from PassTools', which technically would be in violation of the Apple Developer Agreement.

So the bottom line is that on this occasion, you may have just been unlucky.

```
// end rant
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Is there anyway to create `PassTypeIdentifiers` outside of developer.apple.com (ex. On a server or in [tag:Obj-C])? I've looked at the Passbook SignPass Project provided by Apple but that doesn't seem to provide much help for my case.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  The only way currently is through the provisioning portal.

Comment: What's funny is Apple's own documentation uses the example pass type identifier `com.example-company.passes.ticket.event-4631A` suggesting a unique identifier for a specific event.  But since my app issues passes for many different events it would be effectively impossible to do this (since every support staff member would then need to pay the Apple tax just to manually issue IDs/certificates to users creating events, if they want Apple Wallet support).  Thus the only way to use a shared id/cert for all event tickets issued by the app, and just include the event ID in the serial # ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You'd think it would be possible for them to issue some kind of immediate certificate and let me sign my own certs with it--love you Apple!

Comment: The only way you can get around this is to co-brand passes with your event customers, and include your organisation contact on the back of the pass.  Then you could use your own certificate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the technician was talking about, but 23.3 refers to a server (likely yours) going through a signing process with the pass before sending the pkpass file to a device.

For high level information, review the "[signing and compressing the pass](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW28)" section of the passbook programming guide.