# Pass Type ID Really Needed?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, passbook

There are lots of websites like passsource.com and api.passdock.com that let you customize and download a pkpass file that can be added to your passbook on iOS 6.  All of these have their own Pass Type ID in the JSON as passTypeIdentifier key.  My question is this.  Why do you have to setup a Pass Type ID if you can build them online and distribute without ever needing one?

Answer (score 0):

There are good reasons why a Pass ID and Apple Developer Account are required to distribute passes commercially. Take a look at this answer for a detailed explanation (and a small rant about one of the services above). [Create Certificate and Pass Type ID at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201853/create-certificate-and-pass-type-id-at-runtime/14219196#14219196)

Comment: So PassKit will allow me to create my own Pass Type ID and certificate?

Comment: No, we provide a few certificates that can be used by free accounts for evaluation only. This is quite clearly laid out in our terms and coditions. Any pass created with one of our certificates has a mandatory legal disclaimer on the back and free passes expire after 14 days. The only way to get your own Pass ID Certificate is by having your own Apple Developer account. You can  upload as many of your own certificates as you like to our service to sign passes using your own ID(s). This will also remove the PassKit disclaimer from the back.

Comment: That's what I was meaning.  I have created Pass Type IDs before.  So, with a free account, can I upload my own pass type ID to use?  On other question, you said that the api can create a pass on our server directly.  What did you mean by that?  The user creates pass, or I create it completely and let them access it via server?

Comment: Yes, you can use your own certificate with our free service. [Here is a guide](http://code.google.com/p/passkit/wiki/UploadingCertificates) on how to create and upload a pass certificate - note that the PassID needs to be signed using our CSR.  For your other question, better to [contact us](http://passkit.com/support.html#/tab-contact-us) directly and we can provide you specific instructions on what you want to achieve.