# Passbook Passes Certificate Creating

Tags: ios, certificate, passbook

I am working on an app that uses passbook, is it allowed to use a single developer account and create pass certificate for three different company instead of each company creating a developers account to use it in the app. Will the app be rejected. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the terms of the Apple Developer Agreement, there is a whole schedule relating to Passbook and the use of the Pass Type ID Certificates.

Passes create a legal obligation between the issuer and the consumer and as such, they should be signed by the entity that is liable to provide the 'real world' action/item/benefit that the pass grants to the holder (more detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201853/create-certificate-and-pass-type-id-at-runtime/14219196#14219196)).

There are also copyright and trademark infringement implications of using a third party company's trademarks, logo or other copyrighted assets in a pass.  Apple permits you to use these with permission, but only where the fulfilment obligation remains with the pass issuer.  E.g. A bar would be permitted to use an image of Budweiser beer in a 'buy one get one free' pass, provided that Budweiser have given them permission to use that image and their trademark for marketing purposes.  The liability to supply the free beer still sits with the pass issuer.

Not knowing what your passes are, or the nature of the benefit they provide, it is difficult to advise on the risk of your app being rejected.  If these are high profile companies, high value passes, or if the passes contain mainstream brands or trademarks, then it is very possible that your app will be rejected if you sign these passes with your own certificate.

If these are 'Mom & Pop' businesses and the passes only provide small benefits, then your app may slide through.  But as with everything Apple, it is impossible to call, and they may even change their mind down the line if you submit an update.  Personally, I'd recommend that you invest $198 and help these companies through the registration process.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will take your advice